# npm command close immediately

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run command npm, it opens another window and close immediately.

However if I try run the same command the npm should run, it works fine.

My environment is Windows 10

```
$ npm start

> angular2-seed@0.0.0 start C:\repos\angular2-seed
> gulp serve.dev --color


$ gulp serve.dev --color
[10:06:52] Requiring external module ts-node/register
[10:07:02] Loading tasks folder C:\repos\angular2-seed\tools\tasks\seed
[10:07:02] Registering task C:\repos\angular2-seed\tools\tasks\seed\build.assets.dev
[10:07:02] Registering task C:\repos\angular2-seed\tools\tasks\seed\build.assets.prod
[10:07:02] Registering task C:\repos\angular2-seed\tools\tasks\seed\build.bundles.app 
...
```

---- UPDATE---

my package.json is the exact same as https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Could you provide your `package.json`?

Comment: added package.json